# Hi there. I am creating a program in tkinter. How to get the coordinates of the cursor position when entering text into the Text component

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a program in tkinter.  How to get the coordinates of the cursor position when entering text into the Text component

Comment: [ask] and [mre]

Comment: It is not clear what *cursor* you refer.  The mouse cursor or the insertion cursor inside the Text widget?

Comment: The answer can be found in available documentation. It's not clear why you're having a problem with this. Please show us what you've tried. Also, please clarify whether you're asking about the text cursor (insertion point) or the mouse cursor.

Comment: Try looking at [Getting the cursor position in Tkinter Entry widget](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/getting-the-cursor-position-in-tkinter-entry-widget#:~:text=Build%20A%20Paint%20Program%20With%20TKinter%20and%20Python&text=Each%20character%20in%20the%20Entry,INSERT%20argument%20in%20this%20function.).

Comment: An input cursor inside a text widget is implied

Answer (score 1):

The index of the cursor is referenced by the string "insert". You can convert that to the form of *line.character* by calling the `index` command:

```
the_cursor = the_text_widget.index("insert")
```